# Django Error :"ImportError No module named djangoproject01"

Tags: django, python-2.7

I have a problem using the following command:

```
python manage.py makemigrations
```

But it prints me an error:

> ImportError: No module named djangoproyect01

[image: error in CMD]

[image: the files of my Django project]

I don't have any idea what would it be.

Comment: I am guessing the name of your project is djangoproyect01? Can you show us your folder layout and the traceback?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have misspelled `djangoproject01` as `djangoproyect01` in the `INSTALLED_APPS` variable in `settings.py` (you have an app named `djangoproject01` but reference `djangoproyect01` instead), this is what is causing your error. Update the last entry in `INSTALLED_APPS` to `'djangoproject01'`.

Make sure you are consistent too, otherwise you will make things more difficult for yourself. It looks like your project sometimes uses the "word" `proyect` and sometimes uses the word `project` (e.g., you also have a directory `DjangoProyects`.

Also, in the future it is best to post the text of your code and any tracebacks you are seeing rather than screen shots.

Comment: thanks for the help, exactly that was the problem!  i'm new in stackoverflow so thanks for the tips!